# Help finding an article (now solved)

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, paper-request

I'm searching for this article:
"Positive solutions for some quasilinear elliptic equations"
Communications on Applied Nonlinear Analysis 3 (1996), no. 4, 89–98.
by Michel Artola and Lucio Boccardo.

Journal data:
Publisher: International Publications
ISSN: 1074133X

I've tried in Mathscinet (it appears but doesn`t have the "article" click option)
I've tried Sci Hub (doesn't have)
I've tried to find the publisher website (didn't find it)

I would be grateful!

Comment: Have you tried writing to either of the authors? E.g. to the email address for Boccardo found [here](http://cvgmt.sns.it/person/72/).

Comment: [This link](https://iris.uniroma1.it/handle/11573/10580#.YBwXRSMmzcs) may be useful.

Comment: I already wrote to Boccardo and he didn't answered yet. But after tour suggestions i'll wrote to Artola. Thank you!